# Hobbyist needs Help!

Tags: power-supply

I have the following transformer: [Hammond 266S6](https://www.hammfg.com/files/parts/pdf/266S6.pdf) Dual 117Vac primaries (BLK-WHT and BRN-ORG) and Dual 3.15Vac secondaries (Red-BLU and GRY-YEL). I would like to be able to create a switchable output of 3.15Vac or 6.3Vac into a two wire lead. I need help with a wiring diagram and the selection of a switch.

Comment: Gary, your question title should explain what you need help with. Every question is seeking help so your title is kind of pointless. Hit the edit link below your question ...

Comment: You also need to say where you are ... at least, in 115V-land or 230V-land.

Comment: You need a 2P2T to configure secondary as shown and hard wire primary to your voltage as shown

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvoRMG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The left side is shown wired for 230V operation,if you want 115V use the other wiring parttern shown on the data sheet

The right side has a switch to select 3.15 or 6.3V output 
use a DPDT switch, you can use a centre-off DPDT switch here if you want.